# accessing TagName of jquery object

Tags: jquery, tagname

I want to know the tagName of the jquery object , i tried :

```
   var obj = $("<div></div>");
   alert($(obj).attr("tagName"));
```

This alert shows me `undefined`. Whats wrong i am doing?

Comment: Don't forget that jQuery objects are collections, so they can wrap one or many DOM elements, text nodes, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tagName` is a property of the underlying DOM element, not an attribute, so you can use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop), which is the jQuery method for accessing/modifying properties:

```
alert($(obj).prop('tagName'));
```

Better, however, is to directly access the DOM property:

```
alert(obj[0].tagName);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the underlying DOM node, as jQuery objects don't have a `tagName` property, and `tagName` is not a property, not an attribute:

```
var obj = $("<div></div>");
alert(obj[0].tagName);
```

Notice that I've also removed the call to jQuery on the 2nd line, since `obj` is already a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

`tagName` is a native DOM element property, it isn't part of jQuery itself. With that in mind, use `$()[0]` to get the DOM element from a jQuery selector, like this:

```
var obj = $("<div></div>");
alert(obj[0].tagName);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Hd5Jn/1)