# tagName returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running a loop on a number of elements and trying to access another set of elements using the ids I get in the loop I attempt to refer to other elements and get their tag, here's my code.

```
function checkRequired(){
    var i = 0;
    $(".required_div").each(function(index){
        if( $(this).html() != '')
        {
            var question_id = $(this).attr('id').substring(9);
            var question_element = $('[name="ry['+question_id+']"');

            console.log(question_element);
            console.log(question_element.tagName);
        }
    });
    console.log(i);
}
```

And this is what I get in the console for each element:

```
1. [textarea#mce_editor_4.tinymce, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, selector: "[name="ry[67]""]
2. undefined
```

I've also tried to access the tagName using prop as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781593/accessing-tagname-of-jquery-object) but that didn't work as it returns `question_element.prop is not a function(…)`.

Comment: try ```question_element[0]```

Comment: @YarGnawh that worked, so $('name=...) gets multiple elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's returning `undefined` because `question_element` is a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/).

You could either access a DOM element in the jQuery object, *then* get the property:

```
question_element[0].tagName
```

or you could use the `.prop()` method:

```
question_element.prop('tagName');
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, I tried prop before but it didn't work, this is what I get:
Uncaught TypeError: question_element.prop is not a function(…)

Comment: @NaguibIhab Did you try `question_element[0].tagName`? That *should* work based on the jQuery you provided. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: That worked Josh, thanks. Why though, does $('name=...) gets multiple elements? or is the element itself encapsulated in an array?

Comment: @NaguibIhab Well, `$(...)` returns a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) which is essentially a collection of DOM elements. The reason `question_element[0].tagName` works is because you are accessing the property of a specific element. However, if `question_element` is a jQuery object, `question_element.prop('tagName')` should work as well, because it will return the property of the first element in the jQuery object.